# Inconsistent 301 redirects at GoDaddy

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, godaddy, domain-registrar

I am getting mixed results when using GoDaddy's built-in URL forwarding feature.  While these redirects work when using the browser, a test with redirectcheck.com sometimes shows the following result:

```
example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /
```

Other times, I see this, which is the correct result:

```
example.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.example2.com
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 03:10:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive

http://www.example2.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 03:10:05 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.22
X-Pingback: http://www.example2.com/xmlrpc.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Why are these results inconsistent?

Comment: Beats me. But you are not the only one to bring up problems with GoDaddy forwarding. If at all possible, it may be better to do it yourself. I will leave room for someone with experience with this feature answer of course.

Comment: How is "GoDaddy's built-in URL forwarding feature" implemented? What URLs are you redirecting from/to. What headers do you see in the browser - is this always consistent? (It may "work" in the browser, but there could still be additional redirects.)